# modprobe vmhgfs gives -- FATAL: Module vmhgfs not found

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-player, shared-folders

I'm trying to get shared folders working in VMware Player 6. My host is a Windows 7 box, and the VM guest is Ubuntu 14.x

I'm trying to share an external drive on my Windows machine (`F:`) with my ubuntu guest-vm.

I've reinstalled vmware-tools, and am following [this guide.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-share-folders-with-your-ubuntu-virtual-machine-guest/) However, when I try `modprobe vmhgfs`, I still just get the error `FATAL: Module vmhgfs not found.`

Comment: I can't answer your question directly: I run a Windows VM under Ubuntu, rather than the other way round, but I do have a suggestion. I use Samba successfully to access several host shares, so this may provide you with a work-round if you install Samba in your VM and share the `F:` drive on the host. This is completely independent of VMware Shared Folders.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I have is that I want to transfer upwards of 100GB of data. I'd rather not transfer it over an external share, since that could take forever.

Comment: I agree that the TCP/IP overhead is higher than direct access, but you are not working over a physical link - it is all handled in the host. Can you share a normal disc folder? If so, the problem could be with VM access to the USB port, which should be dismounted in the host OS. If you have the disc space, use the host to make a hard disc mirror of the USB, share this, transfer your data, then copy back to the USB disc afterwards.

Comment: I've created a Ubuntu 14.04 VM and found exactly your observations, though in my case I was using Ubuntu as host. It appeared that installing `vmtools` made no difference to the VM, unlike in Windows, where a new graphics driver was installed. I then found [this link](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/resolving-no-shared-folders-with-vmware-player-7-and-ubuntu-15-04-guest/), which confirms that `vmtools` is indeed broken, and proposes a solution, though I haven't had time to investigate that yet. The link you cite refers to much earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I have done a test of copying a 600MB directory from a USB drive into the virtual disc. It took ~45 seconds using Samba on the Ubuntu VM, and took almost the same time using Shared Folders on a Windows VM. This represents 13-14MB/sec on both systems, which is not wonderful, but it does show that there is little penalty in using Samba. On these figures your 100GB should take around 2 hours to transfer.

Comment: I've now followed the instructions in the link and everything is working, with an Ubuntu host at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a Ubuntu 14.04 VM and found exactly your observations, though in my case I was using Ubuntu as host.

It appeared that installing `vmtools` made no difference to the VM, unlike in Windows, where a new graphics driver was installed. It seems that the link you cite refers to much earlier versions of Ubuntu.

I then found [this link](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/resolving-no-shared-folders-with-vmware-player-7-and-ubuntu-15-04-guest/), which confirms that `vmtools` is indeed broken, and I have installed the proposed solution. Everything installed exactly according to the instructions, so VMware's **Shared Folders** feature now works with an Ubuntu host, and there is every reason to hope that it will work with a Windows host.

By the way, addressing your performance concerns, I copied a 600MB folder from the USB drive to the VM Desktop: with the Ubuntu VM using Samba and a Windows VM using **Shared Folders** it took ~45 seconds, and with the Ubuntu VM now using **Shared Folders** it was marginally faster at 40 Seconds, but this margin could easily be caused by other activities or caching. It indicates that your 100GB transfer will take around 2 hours.

Thank you for the question: it raised some interesting issues.